# Spacy EntityRuler - Tagging multiple labels on a single entity

Tags: spacy, named-entity-recognition

I want to tag multiple labels on a single keyword. For ex: "Lemon Soda Drink" , I want Lemon to tagged as FRUIT and FLAVOR both. I have added both the patterns but it only shows one of the labels